# Don't have 2K reputations, so cannot correct a single typo which is bizzare

Tags: feature-request, editing, privileges

Before asking this question, I was to the question exact duplicate of [this.](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1170/why-the-minimum-6-characters-limit-on-edits)

I don't have 2K reputation, so every edit I do requires a minimum of 6 characters to be edited. However I came across [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/133533/how-to-remove-ubuntu-and-put-windows-back-on/143482#143482) question, where there is only one singly typo which is making bizarre sense.

The first paragraph says something like this, and this really makes wrong sense unless the word **with is changed to without**

> You cannot install Windows **with** a genuine Purchased Product Key
>   though, as these ISO files are 100% legal and will only install as an
>   Evaluation copy for 30 days without a product key.

Additionally I would like to know your opinion, as a feature request;

Isn't it a good idea that the edit limit should not be solely measured from the reputation, but should also consider the number of edits he make.
One can even get a great reputation by winning a bounty, which definitely means the user is knowledgeable but might not be a good editor!

Comment: Personally, I do not understand the point of the question posted here. You obviously know how to research, you found an answer to your own question. There is a minimum rep cap for that privilege see http://meta.askubuntu.com/faq#reputation If you disagree with the operations feel free to use the contact button at the bottom of the page http://meta.askubuntu.com/help

Comment: in a gist, i would like to say that if a user don't have enough reputation, but is actively involved in good edits, then the reputation criteria should not be the only thing to judge ! start considering how much edits one make !

Comment: We do, that is why you gain reputation until 2k for every edit you make. After that you should be able to do it by yourself and you will have the powers to do it... :)

Comment: Just find something else to edit, possibly fix grammar provide more links for reference, or fix formatting issues. Almost every post I've come across has at least six characters to be edited within the post.

Comment: Is the mispelling of bizzarre intentional?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just searching for something to reach the 6 character limit is bizarre gymnastics.

You should correct things which are wrong or of bad style. Whether or not an edit is minor or not does not depend on the size - it is only vaguely related.

The rule enforces what it declares to fight: minor edits.

The rule should be dropped. Maybe it is ok for the beginning, below 200 reputation.

Else it encourages ugly workarounds, where people insert hidden comments.

```
<!-- but we don't leak how to do them! -->
```

Answer (score 3):

To overcome the 6 chars limit we need some inspiration on how to do it, as it was already pointed out here:

- [Why the minimum 6 characters limit on edits](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1170/why-the-minimum-6-characters-limit-on-edits)

Usually there will always be some further edits that can be done to reach 6 chars. In your example case one possibility would be the following edit:

> You cannot install Windows as these ISO files are 100% legal but will only install as an Evaluation copy for 30 days without a product key.

In the extremely rare case where really not more than 6 chars can be edited we can always ask another user to do it (e.g. [in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/201/ask-ubuntu-general-room)), or just leave a comment for the owner to edit their own post.

Comment: I'd just like to bring up that edits that are requested in chat that have *no* positive side may not be performed as they either make the post worse, or they are just useless bumping. There are uses, however, for small, two-letter edits.

Comment: @ObsessiveSSOℲ: exactly. I was thinking of such small but important edits that may urgently be needed when there is a typo e.g. in code or an URL.