# When correcting a vital typo via edit, how to bypass 6-character limit on edits

Tags: discussion, editing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to make small but important edits?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/3906/how-to-make-small-but-important-edits)

Say that you have the prototype scenario in [Why the minimum 6 characters limit on edits](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1170/why-the-minimum-6-characters-limit-on-edits): someone has written `rm -rf / foo` instead of `rm -rf /foo` as an answer to a question, and you want to edit that ASAP to help out the unwary copy-pasters. Say that the answer is otherwise correct. The current system will not let you make an edit of less than 6 characters, whitespace or deletions not counting a such.

Should you go out of your way to reformat and rephrase, or should you add a blurb to the end of the answer saying "changed this"? (which would be redundant with the edit message itself)...

Comment: ok, will use the hints there. Did not find them first-time I searched.

Answer (score 3):

If you can't absolutely make six whole character changes in an edit, then as a last resort you can flag the post for moderator attention. I'm willing to bet that nearly all questions can be edited to modify at least 6 character. Whether it's spelling, grammatical, or formatting there's more often than not something to be changed.